# Construct 3 dimensions array from two dimensions array using tile

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `arr = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])`

I want to contract array of following shape `promo_class.shape` which is `(2,3,3)`

I want to create repeated array of shape `(2,3,3)`

```
array([[[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],
       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Any idea how to do that with  `np.tile` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) for a `view` -

```
In [142]: arr = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])

In [144]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(2,3,3))
Out[144]: 
array([[[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

#### Why should we use `view`?

Because being a view, it has no extra memory overhead and hence virtually free on runtime -

```
In [148]: arr = np.random.rand(300)

In [149]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(arr,(200,300,300))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.13 µs per loop
```

If you need an output with its own memory space, append with `.copy()`.

---

If you are *devoted* to `np.tile` -

```
In [174]: np.tile(arr,(2,3,1))
Out[174]: 
array([[[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Is that possible to make the same thing with np.tile function ?

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for. I need tile as Keras backend supports only tile function.