# Concatenate an array with itself n times

Tags: numpy

Given the array `[3, 2, 1]` of shape `(3,)`, I would like to expand it into a 2D array of `(n, 3)`, repeating the array downwards, so where n=3 it would be:

```
[[3, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 1]]
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

(Another way of putting it: I can create n copies of a list with li * n. Is there a way to do this with arrays? If so, I could use that as input and reshape to `(n,3)`)

Comment: You can use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), if you want a new contiguous array, or [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), if you just need a broadcasted view.

Comment: This looks like `(n,3)`, not `(3,n)`?

Comment: `your_array[None][np.zeros(n,int)]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem fixed, sorry

Comment: @jdehesa that's it, thanks. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it

Comment: There are a bunch of similar questions, e.g. I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55607273/1782792) may be a duplicate? It has a good explanation too.

Comment: OK. I basically forgot about the concept of broadcasting and couldn't find it by searching. Maybe it'll be helpful to someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
x = np.array([3,2,1])

x = x.reshape(1,3) # replace 3 with num elems in your array

np.repeat(a=x, repeats=3, axis=0) # replace 3 with number of repeats you want

>>>
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Hope this helped..